# Can you explain the math generating this fractal?

Tags: markov-chains, fractals

I was working on a problem for my job that involved transitioning from a binary vector of length 7 to another binary vector of length 7. The only rule in the transition is that no "1" element in the "from vector" can become a "0" in the "to vector". If I create all possible states and check for valid transitions (like shown here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyOw2.jpg) I end up with this (when scaled): https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4bTQ.jpg.

Once I listed all possible binary states I but a 1 if it was an allowed transition, and a 0 if it was not allowed (i colored the 0's red). Here are some examples with smaller vectors:
(0,0,0)->(0,0,1) is allowed
(0,0,0)->(0,0,0) is allowed
(1,0,0)->(1,0,1) is allowed
(1,0,0)->(0,0,1) is not allowed. The first 1 went to a 0, breaking the only rule, so the whole transition is listed in the matrix as a 0 because it is an invalid transition.

Comment: Numberphile put out a video on chaos theory recently that covers the generation of tje sierpinski triangle.

Comment: I saw that like 2 days before working on this. This arose from working on a slot machine.

Comment: In fact, why not do what @rajb245 suggests *now*?

Comment: @TheCount it appears MiraMath has tried to add some details now, so I deleted my original comment

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose those links are fairly cumbersome to put into a post.

Comment: @MiraMath it's still rather unclear what you're asking though. Can you clarify? Specifically, how are you creating all possible states (is this just counting up from zero to 127) ? Can you write a little more about your "transition rules"? And what parts of your calculations are plotted to give the Sierpinski triangle?

Answer (score 2):

I think the emergence of the 2D fractal is a property of the ordering of the coordinates, which themselves have a fractal nature in binary notation.  See the edges of this figure:

[image: counting fractal]

Source code for the figure, a visualisation of $2017$ in the context of [OEIS A134169](https://oeis.org/A134169), is on my [blog post](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2017-01-08_rollover_2017.html).

Comment: [+1] very very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cellular automata modelizing a form of Sierpinski triangle.

See rule 60 in (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiSieve.html).

See this paper considering it as a biological model (http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.0020424)

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. I upvoted you but I don't have the reputation for it to display visually.